# Change base_url in android after the apk has been build?

Tags: android

So, the scenario is like I have the build an apk with production_base_url but I have admin access so I can change base_url to debug_base_url. Generally, we change build flavor and create a new build with the desired base_url. But I want to do it by changing an option within the app. And base_url will get changed. For instance, I have a production build point to production_base_url after changing option this production build will now point to debug_base_url, How can I do it?

Comment: You need to code for that

Comment: @MD can you tell me what can flow for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switch widget. when turned ON, use it for production and when OFF, use it for debug. You may store your both Base URLs in the SharedPreference in the launcher Activity. Then as per the switch status, load the appropriate Base URL for API call.

Comment: In this case, a lot many things go wrong. Suppose, I have log-in using production_base_url so I have all production data but If I change base_url it will fetch debug data. It's a mess. Some production data or debug or either I have to throw user again for login. I don't want re-login.

Comment: Can you suggest me someway where user doesn't need to re-login?

Comment: It is unavoidable! Whenever user changes the switch status, he/she have to re-login. That should be the case